# Could you please suggest good resources to learn java spring annotations?

Tags: spring-mvc

I need resources with good coverage on annotations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Book : Spring in action (latest version)
SpringFramework documentation : ["Spring anotation-config"](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config)

Answer (score 0):

Also http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/spring-annotations